# Disable multiple buttons using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Razor foreach loop in my MVC view which will generate a number of table rows containing buttons:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Id</td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="btn" class="button btn-primary" type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("RunSingleTest", "Home", new {testName=@item.Test_type, id=@item.Id})'"> Run Test</button>
                        <img id="loading" src="img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="" style="display:none;" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

I want to disable button on click and show loading spinner, however this doesn't work the way I do. (it works in my other page when there's single button)

this is my script:

```
$(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        $('#btn').attr("disabled", "true");
        $('#loading').show();
    });
});
```

How to make it work in foreach?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `id`, use `class`. `$('#btn')` will return only the first element that has this id, even if there are more.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the id's of your elements are unique. According to the html standard you can not have duplicated id's.

I changed your code a bit to fit the snippet and to work better.

- Using `prop()` instead of `attr()` because it support properties a lot better.
- Added an iteration number to the id's in the loop.
- Added class to the loading element for a common jQuery/Css selector
- used `$(this)` selector to get the current clicked buttons. Because of this had to use the `sublings()` function to get the corresponding `<img>` element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').on('click', function () {
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        $(this).siblings('.loading').show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
      <button id="btn1" class="button btn-primary" type="button"> Run Test</button>
      <img id="loading1" class="loading" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="" style="display:none;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
      <button id="btn2" class="button btn-primary" type="button"> Run Test</button>
      <img id="loading2" class="loading" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="" style="display:none;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>
      <button id="btn3" class="button btn-primary" type="button"> Run Test</button>
      <img id="loading3" class="loading" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="" style="display:none;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple buttons (or any other HTML element) with the same ID is not valid HTML. IDs are meant to be unique identifiers of the element - after all, if they weren't they'd no longer be fit to call an "ID"!

Consequently, your "click" handler will only ever be bound to the first element which has that ID. JavaScript is only expecting one matching element, and will not even consider all the others.

You need to use classes instead:

```
$('.button').click(function () {
```

will bind to all buttons with the "button" CSS class.

You can then use `$(this)` to get hold of the current button. You'll need to traverse the DOM to get the nearest "loading" element (which also needs to use ca class instead of an ID).

Also you should use `.prop()` to set the "disabled" *property* (note, not attribute!) instead of `.attr()` as documented here: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

If we add all that together we get something like:

```
$(function () {
    $('.button').click(function () {
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        $(this).siblings('.loading').show();
    });
});
```

in the jQuery, and

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.Id</td>
        <td>
            <button class="button btn-primary" type="button"> Run Test</button>
            <img class="loading" src="img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="" style="display:none;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

---

BTW in your code you seem to have a jQuery "click" function *and* an inline "onclick" event handler. This is not good from a maintainability perspective - better to choose a style and stick to it. Also since your "onclick" navigates the user to another page, all other changes you do in the jQuery handler will be lost immediately in any case. I have removed it in the example above, as it's unclear what is purpose really is, or if it's needed.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code to disable the button.

```
   $(function () {
        $('#btn').click(function () {
            $(this).prop("disabled",true);
            $('#loading').show();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

You can still trigger it by the id's of the buttons, but it has to be done this way:

```
$('[id^=btn]').click(function () {
    $(this).prop("disabled", "true");
    $(this).siblings('#loading').show();
});
```

That will allow the individual button to be disabled when it's clicked and also only show the image that is in relation to the button clicked.

Comment: Having duplicated id's goes against html standards.Do not do that. It's asking for problems.

Comment: What type of problems?

Comment: ones where two buttons with the same ID aren't matched by an ID selector. Your attribute selector here is an inefficient hack to get round the fact that the HTML is not valid.

Comment: @parrigin777 depends on how strict the browser/engine implements the standard. Most are pretty forgiven but in worse case scenario, your site wont load at all.